# Simple lightbox feedback form? Included screenshot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, feedback, jtag

There are so many lightboxes to choose from, I'm looking for a very lightweight one to use in an embedded javascript widget that would be a single domain name. I saw the perfect one on chainreactioncycles.com, it popped up out of nowhere so I took a screenshot:

[image: lightbox]

I tried looking for info on it on the page source, but couldn't find anything that would let me trace where it came from... Would anybody know of one like this? Or exactly that one?

If not exactly like above, anything similar would be great too, keeping the following in mind:
Very small javascript download (animation not needed)
Self contained, not dependent on any libraries other than jquery (since I'm already using that anyway).
Works in major browsers
Close button (like GetSatisfaction or UserVoice)
Dims background
Avoids javascript namespace conflicts (or can easily be made to avoid them)
CSS styling of lightbox does not interfere with site styling

Have you used an existing lightbox scripts for this same purpose with similar requirements? Did you roll your own? Insights welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *modal box*.

[Here is a list of them](http://www.webgurusdesignblog.com/2009/02/10-best-modal-boxes-for-web-design-projects/)

[... and here is a striking replica of what you are looking for](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Zoombox.. It sounds like what you're looking for... Simple to use... Allows custom content.. jQuery Module... From past experience it covers what you have outlined as requirements etc

http://www.grafikart.fr/zoombox will tell you all you need to know.